# With Glide Compose GlideImage composable function, how to enable disk caching

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack, android-glide

According to GlideImage [documentation](https://bumptech.github.io/glide/javadocs/4140/integration/compose/com.bumptech.glide.integration.compose/-glide-image.html), there is RequestBuilderTransform parameter, not sure if this can help. But again cannot find any example or documentation on this. I want to cache loaded images in the disk.

Or, is there a global option we can set while using Jetpack Compose?

Using `implementation "com.github.bumptech.glide:compose:1.0.0-beta01"`.

Comment: If you want to use coil, this video will help. [Coil image cashing](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qQVCtkg-O7w&ab_channel=PhilippLackner)

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know you have two options:

**1.** Enable disk caching globally, This approach will apply disk caching to all image loading operations within your application:

```
   GlideApp
   .with(applicationContext)
   .applyDefaultRequestOptions(
    RequestOptions().diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.ALL) )
```

**2.** Or for each request, this will load the image from the provided URL and cache both the original and resized versions on the storage

```
    GlideImage(imageModel = { imageUrl },
       requestOptions = { RequestOptions()
          .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.ALL)
       })
```